# How can I make django output the day of the week? both in views an in templates

Tags: python, django, date, django-templates, django-views

How can I make django output the day of the week? both in views  an in templates

Not sure how else to elaborate. I'm looking for a way to make django tell me what day of the week it is today, I tried looking at the python functions but didnt quite understand it. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you asking about the today's date, you can use [`now` template tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/templates/builtins/#now) with an `l` format string representing a weekday name:

```
It is {% now "l" %} today.
```

Example:

```
>>> from django.template import Template, Context
>>> t = Template('It is {% now "l" %} today.')
>>> t.render(Context({}))
u'It is Tuesday today.'
```

The same format applies to the [`date` template filter](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/templates/builtins/#date):

```
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> t = Template('It is {{ dt | date:"l" }} today.')
>>> c = Context({'dt': datetime.today()})
>>> t.render(c)
u'It is Tuesday today.'
```

---

In the view, you can use [`strftime()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.date.strftime) to format a `datetime`. [`%A`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior) format string refers to a weekday:

```
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> dt = datetime.today()
>>> dt.strftime('%A')
'Tuesday'
```